# HAML - Append <li> if user is signed in

Tags: html-lists, haml

Using HAML, im trying to append the list item if the user is signed in. The if statement works correctly, but it is writing the list item outside of the unordered list.

```
%footer.site-footer
 %ul
  %li
   %a( title="Contact Us" href="/contact/" ) Contact
  %li
   %a( title="Contact Us" href="/about/#faq" ) FAQ
  %li
   %a( title="Contact Us" href="/terms/" ) Terms
  - if ( !is_user() )
  %li
   %a( title="Contact Us" href="/sign-in/" ) Sign In
```

Comment: That code will print _all_ the `li`s outside the `ul`. You need to check and fix your indentation.

Comment: Yeah, the indents didn't convert to stackoverflow very well.

Comment: Has the indentation been fixed? If not, you most likely need to nest the `%li` inside the `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the `li` is indented under the `if` statement:

```
%footer.site-footer
  %ul
    %li
      %a( title="Contact Us" href="/contact/" ) Contact
    %li
      %a( title="Contact Us" href="/about/#faq" ) FAQ
    %li
      %a( title="Contact Us" href="/terms/" ) Terms
    - if ( !is_user() )
      %li
        %a( title="Contact Us" href="/sign-in/" ) Sign In
```

It won‘t have the same indentation as the other `li`s, but will appear at the right point in the output.

Comment: Thank you Matt, that was the deal.